# How can I inject a static CSS File in GWT like it is done with JS Files?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I want to inject a static css file: app.css into my app.

I know how it is done with JS file. There you can use the ScriptInjector as:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(pathToJsFile)
    .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
    .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {


        }

    })
    .inject();
```

I found StyleInjector but there seems to be no way to do the same thing like: StyleInjector.fromUrl(...)-

**How can I add static css files into my GWT application?**

**Edit:**

my static css file looks like this:

```
* {

}

html {

}


body {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put an interface like this and import the css file into the same package

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final MyResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyResources.class);
    @Source("dastylez.css")
    @CssResource.NotStrict
    CssResource css();
}
```

and in your entry point module or somewhere accessible by it put

```
MyResources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
```